# How to list recent N files in bash shell?

Tags: bash, shell, find, ls

How to list most recently modified max N (such as 5) files in bash?

I used

```
ls -alt
```

or

`find -mtime 0`

to show the recently files but I don't know how to limit the result into 5 records. Maybe find or some other command can be followed in command pipe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `head` or `tail` to limit the number oflines in a pipie:

```
ls -latr | tail -n5
```

Comment: head is just want I want. Thanks!